# Show authentication prompt with only device credential option on Android 10 and lower

Tags: android, android-10.0, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, keyguard

I can display biometric prompt with device credentials using `'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha03'` as,

```
val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Login to My App")
            .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
            .setConfirmationRequired(false)
            .setAllowedAuthenticators(BIOMETRIC_WEAK or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
            .build()
```

Now I want this prompt to show only device credential option(pin/pattern) without biometrics on Android 10 and before, even if its being enrolled in device security.

As per [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth), `BiometricPrompt.setAllowedAuthenticators(DEVICE_CREDENTIALS)`, this isn't supported on Android 10 (API level 29) and lower.

And `KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(..)` this by default includes both biometric and device credentials. I couldn't find any customization for `KeyguardManager`.

Is there any other way to display only device credential option without biometrics?